# How do I install pytest on virtualenv when the python package is installed on the local machine and not in the virtualenv?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, onnx

This is the error I get I am trying to install pytest and nbval for ONNX framework in virtual environment.I have limited memory for the home directory(~/). When i try to change the IPython directory path using the variable $IPYTHONDIR, it indicates that the modules mentioned in the pytest are missing 
When I run the test in virtualenv I get the following result.

```
platform linux -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /local/mnt2/workspace2/Virtual_Env/venv-onnx
plugins: nbval-0.9.5
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

================================================================================================================== ERRORS ===================================================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test session _______________________________________________________________________________________________________
lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:495: in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[key]
E   KeyError: PosixPath('/local/mnt2/workspace2/Virtual_Env/venv-onnx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:501: in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:983: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:967: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:677: in _load_unlocked
    ???
lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:152: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/conftest.py:69: in <module>
    inject()
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/conftest.py:59: in inject
    builtins._ip = get_ipython()
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/conftest.py:21: in get_ipython
    shell = TerminalInteractiveShell.instance(config=config)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py:412: in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py:520: in __init__
    super(TerminalInteractiveShell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:637: in __init__
    self.init_ipython_dir(ipython_dir)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:737: in init_ipython_dir
    self.ipython_dir = get_ipython_dir()
lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:585: in __set__
    self.set(obj, value)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:574: in set
    obj._notify_trait(self.name, old_value, new_value)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:1139: in _notify_trait
    type='change',
lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py:1176: in notify_change
    c(change)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:714: in _ipython_dir_changed
    ensure_dir_exists(change['new'])
lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:431: in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py:223: in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
E   OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '/usr2/tkavathe/.ipython'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:383: in visit
    for x in Visitor(fil, rec, ignore, bf, sort).gen(self):
lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:435: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:435: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:435: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:424: in gen
    dirs = self.optsort([p for p in entries
lib/python3.7/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:425: in <listcomp>
    if p.check(dir=1) and (rec is None or rec(p))])
lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/nodes.py:506: in _recurse
    ihook = self._gethookproxy(dirpath)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/nodes.py:487: in _gethookproxy
    my_conftestmodules = pm._getconftestmodules(fspath)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:473: in _getconftestmodules
    mod = self._importconftest(conftestpath)
lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:509: in _importconftest
    raise ConftestImportFailure(conftestpath, sys.exc_info())
E   _pytest.config.ConftestImportFailure: (local('/local/mnt2/workspace2/Virtual_Env/venv-onnx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/conftest.py'), (<class 'OSError'>, OSError(122, 'Disk quota exceeded'), <traceback object at 0x7f1874042460>))
========================================================================================================== short test summary info ==========================================================================================================
ERROR  - _pytest.config.ConftestImportFailure: (local('/local/mnt2/workspace2/Virtual_Env/venv-onnx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/conftest.py'), (<class 'OSError'>, OSError(122, 'Disk quota exceeded'), <traceback object at 0x7f1...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================================= 1 error in 0.34s ==============================================================================================================
```

Comment: That error says you are out of disk space (quota) for your user

Comment: @jordanm I am aware that my disk space for used is being exceeded. But I would like to know how can I create a temp folder at another location since I don't have access to that user space

Answer (score 1):

Please clear all the temp folder and all the unwanted file.

Your stacktrace clearly says that disk quota exceeded.
The disk quota is the maximum amount of data you're allowed to store in a given disk or location

Comment: Hi, I am not able to change the disk space and cannot remove the files as they are necessary. Is there a way to change the path during installation of pytest?

Comment: Try using altinstall